# How do I dynamically evaluate an event?

Tags: c#, if-statement, event-handling, multiple-conditions

Please forgive me if this should be phrased differently in a programming context - I have no idea what to search for other than exactly what I used to title my question.

Context - I am attempting to build a word search game involving a 4x4 grid of random letters. I'm currently using a Label_Click event to change the background color of the label containing a given letter. In the future there will be many other actions than just this (evaluating whether an array of clicks forms a legitimate word, for instance), but I'm fundamentally stuck with this problem:

```
// pseudo-code

if (lblA1_wasClicked || lblB1_wasClicked || ... lblD4_wasClicked)
{ 
    whichever_wasClicked... //perform actions
}
```

Perhaps I need to learn about creating an event handler for this situation? I have never created a custom event handler, I just know what they are in theory. I am kind of stuck and at this point it's tough to know what to search for to keep learning. I know only enough to be dangerous, so please go easy on me if the answer is as straight-forward as my question feels. :)

Comment: Is this a web forms application? You could check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183356/single-event-handler-for-multiple-links-buttons-on-asp-net

Comment: No, it's a Windows Form Application I've just started working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the ui, you can go to the properties of each label and set their Click handler to the same method. so if you have a method with a signature like this.

```
public void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Then assign that to each label and then use that to process each one. This is a naive example, and there are much better methods that use established patterns for creating windows forms applications. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595469/ui-design-pattern-for-windows-forms-like-mvvm-for-wpf) or search for MVP pattern windows forms to get more info on it!

Comment: So can the label properties be referenced through sender?  Is that what that argument is for? I'll try this in the morning and mark accepted if it does what I think it will do!

Comment: @armadadrive Yes the label properties can be addressed through the sender object, you will need to cast it to a Label though: `var lbl = (Label)sender;`

Comment: This works like a charm! It's exactly what I needed. And @MarkHall, thank you for the casting tip.